# Apply customize patch to magento/framework

Tags: magento2, patches, framework

Have installed "cweagans/composer-patches": "^1.7",
and

```
"extra": {
        "magento-force": "override",
        "composer-exit-on-patch-failure": true,
        "patches": {
            "magento/module-framework": {
                "Render refresh meta": "m2-hotfixes/render_refresh_meta.patch"
            },
            "magento/module-customer": {
                "Render refresh Customer": "m2-hotfixes/my_test_patch.patch"
            }
        }
    }
```

when run composer install, only patch for customer applied. How to apply patch for framework?

```
diff --git a/vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Config/Renderer.php b/vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Config/Renderer.php
index bc4fe6718..b2613d916 100644
--- a/vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Config/Renderer.php
+++ b/vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Config/Renderer.php
@@ -9,6 +9,7 @@
 use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
 use Magento\Framework\View\Asset\GroupedCollection;
 use Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config;
+use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
```

here is file for render_refresh_meta.patch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After research, it should use magento/framework instead of magento/module-framework. Hope this can help people who create patch for framework. When finish composer.json, run composer install -vvv to verify if patch correct or not.